# What can I do in Photokina?

Tags: learning, event

I plan to go to [Photokina 2010](http://www.photokina-cologne.com/) but a little bit unsure about what to expect. Beside exhibition, what exactly can I do in Photokina?

- I've heard that **you can try any
  camera you want**, is that correct?
- Are the exhibitors usually offer some
  kind of discount to the guests?

Comment: I think this is not really a photography question, it should be marked as Community Wiki.

Comment: Wish I could go... :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your specific questions, the answers are 'no' and 'not really'.  Both derive from the fact that photokina's more of an industry exhibition than a consumer show.

When I was there two years ago, there were a number of cameras that were only on display, or only available to the press.  Not many, but a few.  There's certainly no shortage of cameras to try.

Also two years ago, Kodak was giving away samples of Ektar film (which was brand new), and like any conference there's promotional items being given away.  I wasn't there looking to buy, but to my eyes it didn't appear there were any vendors set up to offer individual sales (large trade orders, on the other hand, are a big part of photokina).  I suppose it would never hurt to ask, but there were definitely no "€100 off for Photokina guests!" signs.

Answer (score 2):

1. you can probably try everything there if you're a representative of a major retail chain or a major wholesale company. As a consumer with no credentials and not looking like you've a few tens of thousands to spend and are seriously interested in buying, no.
2. That's not what they're there for. Maybe the above mentioned large accounts will get a show discount, or preferred shipping on newly introduced hardware, but that's it. And they might of course pass that on to you, the consumer, when you buy it in their own stores.